# While comparing head to nullptr: ,,Exception thrown: read access violation. this was 0x20."

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list, nullptr

I'm trying to implement a graph using adjacency list, but in the A_List class function called ,,AddGraphEdge" , there's a problem ,,Exception thrown: read access violation.this was 0x20." It occurs in the list.cpp function ,,AddEdge" when I do if(head==nullptr). I just simply check if head is null. When i delete this statement in place when I assign head=new_edge it tells me the same problem. It works fine if I'm using only normal list, and i create an list object in main and call AddEdge function. I don't know why calling this function in another causes problems.

### Graph.h

```
class Graph
{
protected:
    int _Vertices;
    int _Edges;
    int _Density;
public:

    Graph() : _Vertices(0), _Edges(0), _Density(0) {};

    Graph(const int& Vertices,const int& Edges, const int& Density) : _Vertices(Vertices), _Density(Density), _Edges(Edges)  {};

    void set_Vertices(const int& Vertices) { _Vertices=Vertices; };

    int get_Vertices() { return _Vertices; };

    void set_Edges(const int& Edges) { _Edges=Edges; };

    int get_Edges() { return _Edges; };

    virtual void DisplayGraph() = 0;

    virtual void Get_Random_Graph() = 0;


};
```

---

### Edge.h

```
class Edge
{
private:

    int _StartVertice;
    int _EndVertice;
    int _weight;
    Edge* _NextEdge;

public:

    Edge():_StartVertice(0), _EndVertice(0), _weight(0), _NextEdge(nullptr) {};

    Edge(const int& StartVertice, const int& EndVertice, const int& weight) : _StartVertice(StartVertice), _EndVertice(EndVertice), _weight(weight), _NextEdge(nullptr) {};

    const int& get_StartVertice() const { return _StartVertice; };

    const int& get_EndVertice() const { return _EndVertice; };

    const int& get_Weight() const { return _weight; };

     Edge* get_NextEdge()  { return _NextEdge; };

    void set_NextEdge(Edge* NextEdge) { _NextEdge = new Edge;  _NextEdge = NextEdge; };

    void set_EdgeValues(const int& StartVertice, const int& EndVertice, const int& weight)
    {
        _StartVertice = StartVertice;
        _EndVertice = EndVertice;
        _weight = weight;
    };
                

};
```

---

### List.h

```
#include "Edge.h"



class List
{
private:

    int ListSize;
    Edge* head;

public:

    ~List() {};

    List() : ListSize(0), head(nullptr) {};

    const Edge* get_head() { return head; };

    const int get_ListSize() { return ListSize; };

    void AddEdge(const int& StartVertice, const int& EndVertice, const int& weigth);

    void DisplayList();


};
```

---

### Adjacency_List.h

```
   #include "List.h"
    #include "Graph.h"
    
    
    class A_List: public Graph
    {
    private:
        List* _Adj_List;
    public:
    
        A_List() : Graph() { _Adj_List = nullptr; };
    
        A_List(const int& Vertices, const int& Edges, const int& Density) : Graph(Vertices, Edges, Density) { _Adj_List = new List[Vertices]; };
    
        virtual void DisplayGraph() override;
    
        virtual void Get_Random_Graph() override;
    
        void AddGraphEdge(const int& StartVertice, const int& EndVertice, const int& weigth);

};
```

---

### List.cpp

```
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>


void List::AddEdge(const int& StartVertice, const int& EndVertice, const int& weigth)
{
    Edge* new_edge = new Edge;

    new_edge->set_EdgeValues(StartVertice, EndVertice, weigth);

    if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = new_edge;
        }

    else
        {
            Edge* tmp = head;
            head = new_edge;
            new_edge->set_NextEdge(tmp);
        }

    ListSize++;
}

void List::DisplayList()
    {
    Edge* tmp = head;

    while (head->get_NextEdge() != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << tmp->get_StartVertice() << tmp->get_Weight() << tmp->get_EndVertice() << std::endl;
            tmp = tmp->get_NextEdge();
        }
    std::cout << tmp->get_StartVertice() << tmp->get_Weight() << tmp->get_EndVertice() <<  std::endl;
    }
```

---

### Adjacency_List.cpp

```
#include "Adjacency_List.h"

    void A_List::AddGraphEdge(const int& StartVertice, const int& EndVertice, const int& weigth)
    {
        _Adj_List[StartVertice].AddEdge(StartVertice, EndVertice, weigth);
    }
    
    
    
     void A_List::DisplayGraph()
    
    {int Vertices = A_List::get_Edges();
    
         for (int i = 0; i < Vertices; i++)
         {
             _Adj_List[i].DisplayList();
         }
    
    }
    
     void A_List::Get_Random_Graph() 
    {
    
    
    
    }
```

---

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Adjacency_List"



int main()
{

    A_List Graph_list;

    Graph_list.AddGraphEdge(4,3,2);

    Graph_list.DisplayGraph();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile...

Comment: What happens? I can compile it without problems, maybe I didnt give some function here?

Comment: a.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `vtable for A_List'
a.cpp:(.text.startup+0x54): undefined reference to `A_List::AddGraphEdge(int const&, int const&, int const&)'
a.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5e): undefined reference to `A_List::DisplayGraph()'

Basically anything related to A_List is missing

Comment: I'm sorry... i accidentally inserted list code instead of adjacency_list... it should be fine now. Only Adjacency_List.cpp was wrong. Sorry...

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Vertices`, `_Edges`, `_Density`, `_StartVertice`, `_EndVertice`, _NextEdge` `_Adj_List`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your naming convention hits undefined behavior.  You _must not_ use leading underscores followed by uppercase letters.  Those are reserved, and your code is always wrong to use such names.  (It's best to use a single _trailing_ undescore instead, to avoid hitting UB for silly reasons like this.

Comment: Here is a another (slightly different?)  list of conventions, https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/2785528, which suggests it is from 2003 c++ standard.  I suspect MS has their own conventions.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your sugestions, I will try to avoid naming variables like this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor sets _Adj_List to nullptr:

```
A_List() : Graph() { _Adj_List = nullptr; };
```

And now it gets dereferenced and used (it's still nullptr):

```
void A_List::AddGraphEdge(const int& StartVertice, const int& EndVertice, const int& weigth)
{
    _Adj_List[StartVertice].AddEdge(StartVertice, EndVertice, weigth);
}
```

But it might not be the only bug, as it's quite messy code

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. Could give me some tips why is this a messy code? I want to improve myself as much as I can.

Comment: @77jt777 Well, for example passing int by const reference to the methods - why? For passing the int by copy is better (it starts paying off with bigger types or objects). Also why don't use standard library std::list/std::vector? Another one is using std::unique_ptr for guarding the memory. You know, rule of three/five, RAII...

Comment: And also const correctness can be applied on class methods, that are not supposed to change anything. Like: `int get_Edges() const { return _Edges; };` - you can use it even if it's called on const instance.